# How to split 1xN vector into MxL vector and fill the rest with zeros?

Tags: matlab, reshape

I have a matrix

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11]
```

I need to split it into rows of 5 and fill the rest of the unset block with zeros like this:

```
transformed = [ 1  2  3  4  5 ;
                6  7  8  9  10;
                11 0  0  0  0 ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could first expand `a` to have the required number of elements like this;

```
a(15) = 0 % Matlab will automatically fill elements 12:14 with 0
```

then

```
transformed = reshape(a,[5,3])'
```

produces

```
ans =

     1     2     3     4     5
     6     7     8     9    10
    11     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: is there any guaratee that it will be filled with 0? what if it will'not and there can be garbage?

Comment: Read the documentation http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/resizing-and-reshaping-matrices.html